# bash script containing function doesn't do anything at all when run

Tags: bash

I'd like to remove some duplicate files from a directory.
In a directory in my `$PATH`, I've written a script `remove_duplicates` containing the following:

```
$:~/local/bin cat remove_duplicates
#!/bin/bash

remove_duplicates() {
  for i in *
  do
#  echo ${i}
    if [ -e ${i}.~1~ ]
    then
      hash1=$(md5sum ${i} | awk '{print $1}')
      hash2=$(md5sum ${i}.~1~ | awk '{print $1}')
      if [ "$hash1" = "$hash2" ]
      then
        rm -v ${i}.~1~
      fi
    fi
  done
}
```

When I execute the script in a directory containing a duplicated file, it doesn't delete the duplicate.

```
$:~/.vim/colors md5sum candycode*
8b115e7b2ed03eb949c9c0b2cf049012  candycode.vim
8b115e7b2ed03eb949c9c0b2cf049012  candycode.vim.~1~

$:~/.vim/colors which remove_duplicates
~/local/bin/remove_duplicates

$:~/.vim/colors remove_duplicates

$:~/.vim/colors md5sum candycode*
8b115e7b2ed03eb949c9c0b2cf049012  candycode.vim
8b115e7b2ed03eb949c9c0b2cf049012  candycode.vim.~1~
```

I think the problem might be in the expansion of the `*` in my `for` loop, but I'm not sure how to get it to expand correctly (i.e. expand to include all files in the directory from which the script is called).
The reason that I think this is where the problem lies is that when I uncomment the `echo ${i}` line in the script, I don't see anything echoed to `stdout`.
I've also tried to replace `*` with `$PWD/*`, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Were you going to add a call to the function?

Comment: I think I had a serious misunderstanding of how bash functions work.  I added another line to the file in order to call the function, and now it works as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: @DrorMoyal, eh? `[ "$foo" = "$bar" ]` is entirely correct; it's `==` that's wrong (in POSIX sh). See the specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: BTW, going forward -- running with `bash -x yourscript` is useful to see what that script *actually does* when it's executed; fewer false positives tracking down an issue that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining a function, but not running it.

That is, when you run this script, it goes through and executes it, line by line.  What this accomplishes is defining a function called `remove_duplicates`.. then it reaches the end of the file and is done.

You can either add a line at the end which calls `remove_duplicates`, or you can just remove the declaration that makes it a function in the first place:

```
#!/bin/bash

  for i in *
  do
#  echo "${i}"
    if [ -e "${i}.~1~" ]
    then
      hash1=$(md5sum "${i}" | awk '{print $1}')
      hash2=$(md5sum "${i}.~1~" | awk '{print $1}')
      if [ "$hash1" = "$hash2" ]
      then
        rm -v "${i}.~1~"
      fi
    fi
  done
```

Comment: Thanks! @Ignacio mentioned this in a comment above, and this solved the problem.  I think I just had a fundamental misconception about the use of bash functions in executable files.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good call -- I just copied and pasted the original, but fixing that potentially *very* messy mistake is a good plan.  Luckily the original should fail gracefullyish, as the `md5sum` command should break first.  Unless both hashes fail, in which case they might match...